# GoogleAppEngine による静的ファイル配信の従量課金について

Tags: google-app-engine

GoogleAppEngine による静的ファイル配信は、どのように課金計算されるのでしょうか。

### 課金計算

下記の認識なのですが、これは正しいでしょうか？

1. [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/#pricing) ページに記載されている「インスタンス時間」と「送信ネットワーク トラフィック」によって計算される(配信ごとに要したインスタンス時間とトラフィックで課金される)。
2. [Static cache expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_cache_expiration) による設定は、アクセスしてくるブラウザに返すキャッシュ関連ヘッダを設定するためのものであり、ユニークアクセスの増加に伴う課金を抑えるものではない。

### 使用料を抑える工夫

[Static cache expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_cache_expiration)以外に、使用料を抑えられるような機能や工夫があれば教えてください。

Comment: 静的ファイルはGAEからでなくGoogle Cloud Storage (GCS CDN)から配信するほうがよいでしょう。「金額的にいくら」とは答えられないのですが、安くなったはず。もっと重要なのは配信性能があがることで、レスポンスタイムが良くなったり、画像のリサイズができたり、DNSラウンドロビン(cdn0.example.com, cdn1.example.com...)でブラウザの同一ドメイン同時ダウンロード数の制限を回避するなどGAE単体ではできない設定が可能です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

静的ファイルの配信のみの場合には基本的にインスタンスは起動されません。
アウトバンドのトラフィックだけでOKです。

2点目はご理解の通りです。

以下、参考にしてください。
http://www.apps-gcp.com/gae_stresstest02/